# Find a date exactly after a month, after two months, after 3 months etc

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset of users' daily status, and I want to find a user's status after each month.

For ex: If a user has his daily status from 09/20/2020 to 03/10/2022. I want to find the status on the following days:

Desired Output:

| Date | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 09/20/2020 | Yes |
| 10/20/2020 | No |
| 11/20/2020 | Yes |
| 12/20/2020 | Yes |

Comment: It is good that you specify a desired *output*, but can you also add your *input*? And some of your own attempts (and how they fail)?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions a little unclear but you may want to look at using a for loop and the DATEADD(MONTH) functions

Comment: Hi, I hope this makes it clear. I have a user who subscribed to a service on 09/20/2020. And he is continuing with his service until March 2022. I have the users' daily status, but I want to retrieve only the monthly status.  i.e, what is the user's status after the first month, second month etc. I tried DATE functions, but couldn't achieve my objective.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE temp TABLE user_status (
    userid bigint DEFAULT 1,
    status_date date,
    status boolean
);

INSERT INTO user_status (status_date, status)
    VALUES ('2020-09-20', TRUE), ('2020-09-21', FALSE), ('2020-09-29', TRUE), ('2020-10-20', FALSE), ('2020-10-22', FALSE), ('2020-10-29', TRUE), ('2020-11-20', TRUE), ('2020-11-24', FALSE), ('2020-11-29', TRUE), ('2020-12-20', TRUE), ('2020-12-24', FALSE), ('2021-11-29', TRUE);
```

then:

```
SELECT
    d::date,
    status
FROM
    generate_series('2020-09-20'::timestamp, '2020-12-20'::timestamp, interval '1 month') d
    LEFT JOIN user_status ON status_date = d
WHERE
    status_date > '2020-09-19'
    AND status_date < '2022-3-10';
```

reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html